# Writing a Feature Test, HTML5 Video Tag

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, html5-video

I am currently writing a feature test for browsers surrounding the HTML5 video tag. I am using Typescript (a version of JavaScript). Someone on my team just asked a great question: does the feature test (that I have written based on [this great article](http://www.nomensa.com/blog/2011/detecting-browser-compatibility-html5-video-and-audio) by Dan Stringer) actually work?

Does the `src` attribute of the `video`tag need to be set for the feature to fail? Or, is it just as simple as attempting to add the `video` tag to the DOM (what I have done)?

```
export function DoesBrowserSupportHTML5VideoAndFileType(fileType : string) {
        var mimeType = "video/" + fileType,
            videoElement = document.createElement("video");

        if (typeof videoElement.canPlayType === "function") {
            // ... Do some mime-type evaluations
            // and return accordingly
        }

        return false; // default
    }
```

Obviosly, this is not currently surrounded by a `try-catch` statement; but, do I need to set the source attribute?

Comment: The way you currently have it appears to be [how Modernizr does it](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/f839e2579da2c6331eaad922ae5cd691aac7ab62/feature-detects/video.js#L47), so I'd think you'll be fine. Did you try testing it?

Comment: @AndrewMyers thanks for the link! Hadn't seen that project before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the src attribute of the videotag need to be set for the feature to fail

Not at all.

However based on the `src` the eventual playback might still fail (might just be a fault of the actual file).

Comment: If I am just adding a `video` element to the DOM, can that cause an error if the `src` attribute is not set?